# Displaying images in table using HTTP 'POST' request

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I am wondering how I can display the images into a table uploaded by a certain device like an "Upload History" option. I have the request retrieving the images as such...

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"device_code=%@", deviceCode];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.urlExample.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

I am retrieving the images fine I just need help putting them into the table. Anyone have an idea on how I could do that?

Comment: Yeah. you should download the image as thumbnail and store them in document folder. then, you can display them in UITableView as normal.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to render image into your custom cell using URL. You can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) to download and stored image into cache memory.

Code to load image into your imageView:

```
#import <SDWebImage/SDWebImage.h>

[YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:YOUR_IMAGE_URL]
             placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```